# Cant access PHP generated files via FTP

Tags: php, ftp

I have a form that uploads files and stores them in an uploads folder in my httpdocs folder. However, if I try to delete or rename one of those files via ftp, it wont let me. Why?

Answer (score 3):

The user your web server runs as (`apache`, or perhaps `www-data` or `httpd` for Apache) probably owns the PHP-created files.  The permissions on them may prevent your FTP user from writing to them.

Comment: Ok all my files and folders are set as owner of vsftpd:nogroup

Answer (score 2):

Because php works under apache username, so you don't have rights to delete other users files. You need to have apache in the same group as your username, or delete using apache username (by scripts, manually, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Why it happens has just been already answered.

You can avoid this by using the `chmod` function giving to the uploaded file the right permission.

Es:

`chmod($filename,666)`

see here: http://it.php.net/chmod